# Persistent bottom sheet with constant initial height for English dictionary lookup

Tags: dart, flutter

I'd like to show the result of a English dictionary lookup in a persistent **bottom sheet**. The results (UTF-8 texts) are **variable in length**, so for **consistency** sake every result is to be displayed with a **initial** height of, say 200.0 dp (In other words the bottom sheet only reveals a fraction of the Text Widget initially). The user may then slide the paper upwards to reveal full content.

How can this be implemented using existing Flutter API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your text in class like `Stack` that has configurable overflow behavior, or put the Text in a fixed container and set its `overflow` property. You could put a `GestureDetector` on it to detect drag events and adjust the size of the bottom sheet.

Consider also putting a bit of a fade out gradient on top to make the overflow look more natural.